# Use python 3 to connect to hive

Tags: python, syntax, hive

i am trying to access hive using python 3.7
i am using pyhive to do it
when i try to use pyhive in python 3.7 i am getting the following error
from pyhive import hive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code_sample.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyhive.hive
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 337
    def execute(self, operation, parameters=None, async=False):
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but when i do the same in python 2.6 version i am not facing any errors

can you please help me with this, if its not possible with pyhive can you suggest some better options to connect to hive with python 3.6 or 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From python 3.7, `async` is a keyword and variables cant be named `async`. So pyhive package needs to be fixed, to work with python3.7

This should work fine with python 3.6, though

There was some discussion about fixing this @ https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/148. You may request the developers to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing the following libraries.

```
thrift==0.11.0
thrift-sasl==0.2.1
bit-array==0.1.0
impyla==0.15.0
thriftpy==0.3.9
```